# Django + Selenium test hangs - deadlock?

Tags: django, selenium

I've been working in a Django project for a while and am starting on a new app, trying to do more automated testing with Selenium at the same time.  I'm using http://www.tdd-django-tutorial.com/ as a guide.

I'm trying to test the ability to log in to my application. My test can pull up the page and fill in text fields without trouble, but when it clicks on the submit button, it hangs - Firefox keeps trying to load the new page but it never happens.  It looks like deadlock to me, but I don't understand it well enough to know what's going on.

Other details: I'm using Django's built-in login view.  I have another test that successfully logs in to the admin site.  I can log in to my application just fine when I test manually.  The application accesses a remote MySQL database.

Here's my test:

```
from django.test import TestCase, LiveServerTestCase
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class BucloudTest(LiveServerTestCase):
"""Tests shared functionality (login, network and app selection)."""

    fixtures = ['24aug2012_dev_auth.json']

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(5)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_good_login(self):
    """Tests that a user can log in using valid credentials."""

        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url + "/login/")
        user_css = "[placeholder=Username]"
        user_field = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector(user_css)
        user_field.send_keys("test_user1")
        pw_css = "[placeholder=Password]"
        pw_field = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector(pw_css)
        pw_field.send_keys("test")
        button = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("[value='Sign in']")
        button.click()
        WebDriverWait(self.browser, 30).until(
            lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body'))
        body = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
        self.assertIn("Properties", body.text)
        print "ran tests YAY!!"
```

I run the test with `manage.py test functests --liveserver=localhost:8080-8090`.

Thanks very much for any suggestions!

Comment: try the login with the TestClient first.

see here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#django.test.client.Client.login
just to be sure that isn't a login problem

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried that and it works fine (runs a little slower than I would have expected though).  I found out that the server I was using was bogged down with another process, and since that's been killed the tests work intermittently.  I can't find a pattern to when they work or not.  I see the same behavior running on a local sqlite database (on Windows 7).  Using Chrome does not run into the same issue, but I get other inconsistent errors (`WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied`).  I'm at the point of abandoning Selenium for now, but any other suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score -1):

It might be due to the fact that the content of your test_good_login() function is not indented

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  That was actually just a typo in my entry, which I just corrected.  The actual code was indented properly.

Comment: what if you replace 
button = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("[value='Sign in']")
button.click() with pw_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)